# Strange Iterator Behavior in g++ 4.7.1

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I originally wrote some code that uses `std::array` in Microsoft VS 2012. However, when porting it to g++ 4.7.1, some issues arose. It was narrowed down to what seems like a difference in iterator behavior between the platforms.

The following is a basic code sample that isolates the difference:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

const std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> scoring_segment_codes_ = {{
    {{1, 2, 0}}, {{3, 4, 0}}, {{99, 100, 0}}
}};

int main()
{
    // This works on: g++ (Debian 4.5.3-9) 4.5.3
    // and Visual Studio 2012 (Windows 8)
    // but NOT g++ (Debian 4.7.1-7) 4.7.1
    for (auto i = scoring_segment_codes_.at(1).begin(); *i != 0; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Bad: " << *i << std::endl;
    } 

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // works on all three
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < scoring_segment_codes_.at(1).size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Good: " << scoring_segment_codes_.at(1)[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // works on all three
    auto bees = scoring_segment_codes_.at(1);
    for (auto i = bees.begin(); *i != 0; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Good: " << *i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this sample on `g++ (Debian 4.5.3-9) 4.5.3` and `Microsoft VC++` is:

```
Bad: 3
Bad: 4

Good: 3
Good: 4
Good: 0

Good: 3
Good: 4
```

This was what I was expecting the output to be. However, `g++ (Debian 4.7.1-7) 4.7.1` produces the output:

```
Bad: 3
Bad: 32513
Bad: 6297664

Good: 3
Good: 4
Good: 0

Good: 3
Good: 4
```

The difference seems to be the way the iterator is retrieved. I had thought the result of `auto i = scoring_segment_codes_.at(1).begin()` is defined behavior. Is it not? Or is the problem something else completely?

If this is an issue with g++ 4.7.1, unfortunately this is a system I am stuck with. Is there anything I can get this to work on g++ 4.7.1? I know going through and making sure all the iterator usage is compatible is an option, but this seems like a very rich source of bugs.

Comment: You need another set of braces around each subarray to remove all warnings.

Comment: @J.N. That is interesting, is this a known bug? Like I said, I really don't think upgrading to 4.7.2 is an option. I'll fix those braces

Comment: I have no idea whether it is known, you can try to search for it here http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/.

Comment: This also gives strange results using 4.7.0 under MinGW. However, changing it from `at(1)` to `[1]` gives the expected results.

Comment: Works on Apple LLVM 4.2 as well fwiw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>As per my comment, the version of g++ I'm using is slightly different (4.7.0). Looking at the actual code for their array implementation gives this:</s>

```
#ifdef __EXCEPTIONS
  constexpr const_reference
  at(size_type __n) const
  {
return __n < _Nm ? 
       _M_instance[__n] : throw out_of_range(__N("array::at"));
  }
//#else path
```

From [Constexpr GCC Wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Constexpr), we have that "A constant expression is noexcept even if it involves a call to a constexpr function that isn't declared noexcept.". Thus it looks like someone has erroneously labelled at as `constexpr` even though it can throw.

I'm not sure if this has been related as a bug report, but it certainly looks like a bug. A temporary fix is to use `operator[]` - but this looks like the reason `operator[]` works and `at` does not.

Edit: To answer the comment, modifying the standard library  header is one possibility, although that certainly has problems.

The other is to perhaps create a wrapper like the following (note that I haven't tested this):

```
template <typename T, std::size_t sz>
const T& at(const std::array<T, sz>& arr, typename std::array<T, sz>::size_type index)
{
    if(index < arr.size())
        return arr[index];
    throw std::out_of_range("array::at");
}
```

Similarly for the non-const reference version. Note that this can call `array.at()` directly as the non-const version of `at()` is correct.

Neither of these solutions is perfect, but they may at least help you work around this bug.

**2nd Edit:** Looking into it more, apparently I'm wrong, it is legal to declare `constexpr` functions that throw utilizing a ternary operator. I'll leave the fix here because it works, but my analysis of what's going on is incorrect.

Comment: That certainly makes sense. Thank you for looking into it. Do you know if there's an easy way to still use array::at for bounds checking when debugging, but switch to [] for release? I couldn't think of anything

Comment: @Kyryx See my edit. I'm not sure if this idea is suitable for you, but it might be a start.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, thank you very much. I'll try the template wrapper, otherwise I'll either modify the library or just switch to [].

Comment: Hmm, well I am going to continue to look into the explanation. The wrapper certainly works perfectly. Thanks again